# Swift - Cleaner Syntax for Reducing an Array inside Guard

Tags: swift, reduce

I have a UIView driven by two arrays: `[Float]` "data" and `[UIColor]` "colors". If the view isn't given proper data I am displaying an empty state, controlled by the guard statement you see here:

```
private func unwrap() -> ([Float], [UIColor]) {
    guard
        let data = data, !data.isEmpty,
        let colors = colors, data.count == colors.count
        else { return ([1], [UIColor.lightGray]) } // empty state

    let total = data.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
    if total == 0 { return ([1], [UIColor.lightGray]) }

    return (data, colors)
}
```

I don't like the repetition of the empty state `return ([1], [UIColor.lightGray])` being used twice. I've tried to add the data.reduce call inside the guard statement, something like:

```
private func unwrap() -> ([Float], [UIColor]) {
    guard
        let data = data, !data.isEmpty,
        let colors = colors, data.count == colors.count,
        data.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 } != 0
        else { return ([1], [UIColor.lightGray]) } // empty state

    return (data, colors)
}
```

...the compiler doesn't understand the syntax

```
private func unwrap() -> ([Float], [UIColor]) {
    guard
        let data = data, !data.isEmpty,
        let colors = colors, data.count == colors.count,
        let total = data.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }, total != 0
        else { return ([1], [UIColor.lightGray]) } // empty state

    return (data, colors)
}
```

...the result of the closure `data.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }` isn't optional so can't be included in the guard declaration.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Avoid using parallel arrays; create a `struct` that holds both a `Float` and a `UIColor`, then have an array of that struct. That way your `data.count == colors.count` precondition just melts away, as it's now enforced by the compiler.

Comment: @Hamish indeed. This is an XY problem.

Comment: In the class this UIView is implemented creating a struct from the source arrays is an unnecessary overhead without a benefit. Makes the implementation more complex, less elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my simplified version:

```
private func unwrap() -> ([Float], [UIColor]) {
    guard let data = data, let colors = colors,
        data.count == colors.count, data.reduce(0, +) != 0  else {
            return ([1], [UIColor.lightGray])
    } // empty state

    return (data, colors)
}
```

Reduce can just use Float's + function, and a reduce on an empty data array will always be 0, so you don't need to check the empty status.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
private func unwrap() -> ([Float], [UIColor]) {
    guard
        let data = data, !data.isEmpty,
        let colors = colors, data.count == colors.count,
        (data.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }) != 0
        else { return ([1], [UIColor.lightGray]) } // empty state

    return (data, colors)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making your return value a computed variable:

```
private func unwrap() -> ([Float], [UIColor]) {
    var emptyVal: ([Float], [UIColor]) {
        return ([1], [UIColor.lightGray])
    }

    guard
        let data = data, !data.isEmpty,
        let colors = colors, data.count == colors.count
        else { return emptyVal } // empty state

    let total = data.reduce(0) { $0 + $1 }
    if total == 0 { return emptyVal }

    return (data, colors)
}
```